# R ComplexHeatMap add value in boxes and remove dendo

Tags: r

How do I combine these two things in R?
I want to hide the dendrogram and show the values?

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
```

This shows values -

```
Heatmap(mat, 
name = "foo", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
{
grid.text(sprintf("%.1f", mat[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))
}
)
```

This hides dendrogram -

```
heatmap(mat, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA)
```

The data -

```
set.seed(123)

mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(16, -1), 4), matrix(rnorm(32, 1), 8)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(24, 1), 4), matrix(rnorm(48, -1), 8)))

# permute the rows and columns
mat = mat[sample(nrow(mat), nrow(mat)), sample(ncol(mat), ncol(mat))]

rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:12)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the dendogram in `ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap` two arguments are available  `show_row_dend` and `show_column_dend`:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
Heatmap(mat, 
        name = "foo", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
        {
          grid.text(sprintf("%.1f", mat[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))
        },
        show_row_dend = FALSE,
        show_column_dend = FALSE)
)
```

[image]

To install the package:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ComplexHeatmap")
```